# Assign pre-determined list of ips for ec2 instances at launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to assign pre-determined list of ips for ec2 instances while launching? If yes then how could we achieve that?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you launching the instances from the Management Console? CLI? SDK? OpsWorks? Have you already allocated the EIPs? Are the EIPs already associated with other instances?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I was looking to assign private ips as my ec2s are in private subnet.

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate EIP - Elastic IP's, and after an instance comes up, assign that EIP to whichever instance you want.

This will work on a small-scale only though, as by default you are only allowed 5 EIP's per region, per account.

If you need more EIPs, you may be able to request it - but if you need a lot more, they may want to help you figure out why you think you need so many, and offer a better option if possible.

You'd need to provide more details for a more specific answer.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I was looking to assign private ips as my ec2s are in private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

In EC2 VPC, you can specify the primary IPv4 address during instance launch, but you'll have to launch one instance at a time. You cannot use this option if you're launching more than one instance in the request.

**Using CLI**

> --private-ip-address (string)
>
> [EC2-VPC] The primary IPv4 address. You must specify a value from the IPv4 address range of the subnet. Only one private IP address can be designated as primary. You can't specify this option if you've specified the option to designate a private IP address as the primary IP address in a network interface specification. You cannot specify this option if you're launching more than one instance in the request.
>
> See [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html).

For example:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-903004f8 --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e --private-ip-address 10.0.1.112
```